# How to use Stream.Write Method to overwrite existing text

Tags: c#, stream

I am using StreamWriter to write records into a file. Now I want to overwrite specific record.

```
string file="c:\\......";
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write));
sw.write(...);
sw.close();
```

I read somewhere here that I can use [Stream.Write method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write.aspx) to do that, I have no previous experience or knowledge of how to deal with bytes.

```
 public override void Write(
    byte[] array,
    int offset,
    int count
)
```

So how to use this method.
I need someone to explain what exactly byte[] array and int count are in this method, and any simple sample code shows how to use this method to overwrite existing record in a file.

ex. change any record like record Mark1287,11100,25| to  Bill9654,22100,30| .

Comment: I assume that file is a binary file? Or is it text based? If it is binary, is each record equally in size or does the size of each record different from record to record?

Comment: use 'using' instead of 'close', it is safer and saves you from typing.

Comment: @martin  right now its text file.what i want is to find a way to create records and directly re-write any of these records given their offset. instead of reading the whole file in run-time and create new file then replace it. and yes each record has different size. i dont mind doing it binary if it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override a particular record, you must use `FileStream.Seek`-method to set the put your stream in position.

Example for `Seek`

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class FStream
{
static void Main()
{
    const string fileName = "Test#@@#.dat";

    // Create random data to write to the file.
    byte[] dataArray = new byte[100000];
    new Random().NextBytes(dataArray);

    using(FileStream  
        fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        // Write the data to the file, byte by byte.
        for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
        {
            fileStream.WriteByte(dataArray[i]);
        }

        // Set the stream position to the beginning of the file.
        fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Read and verify the data.
        for(int i = 0; i < fileStream.Length; i++)
        {
            if(dataArray[i] != fileStream.ReadByte())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error writing data.");
                return;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The data was written to {0} " +
            "and verified.", fileStream.Name);
    }
}
}
```

After having sought the position, use `Write`, whereas

```
public override void Write(
byte[] array,
int offset,
int count
)

Parameters
array
Type: System.Byte[]
The buffer containing data to write to the stream.
offset

Type: System.Int32
The zero-based byte offset in array from which to begin copying bytes to the stream.

count
Type: System.Int32
The maximum number of bytes to write.
```

And most important: always consider the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.write.aspx) when unsure!

Answer (score 1):

So... in short:

- Your file is text base (but is allowed to become binary based).
- Your record have various sizes.

This way there is, without analyzing your file, no way to know where a given record starts and ends. If you want to overwrite a record, the new record can be larger than the old record, so all records further in that file will have to be moved.

This requires a complex management system. Options could be:

- When your application starts it analyzes your file and stores in memory the start and length of each record.
- There is a seperate (binary)file which holds per record the start and length of each record. This will cost an additional 8 bytes in total (an Int32 for both start+length. Perhapse you want to conside Int64.)

If you want to rewrite a record, u can use this "record/start/length"-system to know where to start to write your record. But before you do that, you have to assure space, thus moving all records after the record being rewritten. Of course you have to update your managementsystem witht the new positions and length.

Another option is to do as a database: every record exists of fixed width columns. Even text columns have a maximum length. Because of this you can calculate very easy where each record start in the file. For example: if each record has a size of 200 bytes, then record #0 will start at position 0, the next record at position 200, the one after that at 400, etc. You do not have to move record when a record is rewritten.

Another suggestion is: create a mangementsystem like how memory is managed. Once a record is written it stays there. The managementsystem keeps a list of allocated portions and free portions of the file. If a new record is written, a free and fitting portion is search by the managementsystem and the record is written at that position (optionally leaving a smaller free portion). When a record is deleted, that space is freeds up. When you rewrite a record you actually delete the old record and write a new record (possibly at a totalle different location).

My last suggestion: Use a database :)

Comment: the reason for "Your file is text base (but is allowed to become binary based)".  is that i'm learning how to do it i'm not bounded with  one strict way of doing it.
Also thanks for these suggestions.